# xsl for each not updating all the values using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, for-loop, xpath

I have the requirement in which I have to updated the values based on certain Xpath condition.

**Input**

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Header/>
<S:Body>
    <ns2:ReturnUpdateRequest xmlns="urn:ibm:uscomm:service:header" xmlns:ns2="ibm:ServiceReturnUpdate" Version="1.0">
        <Header>
            <DocumentIdentifier>0001013083-1436198976111</DocumentIdentifier>
            <DocumentDateTime>2015-07-06T13:09:36.111-03:00</DocumentDateTime>
            <From>
                <PartnerName>MYibm_ONLINE</PartnerName>
                <PartnerIdentifier type="USER_ID">0001013083</PartnerIdentifier>
            </From>
            <DataSource>MYibm_ONLINE</DataSource>
        </Header>
        <ns2:ReturnUpdateRequestBody>
            <ns2:DealerEntity>
                <ns2:PartnerIdentifier Type="SAP_ID">0001013083</ns2:PartnerIdentifier>
            </ns2:DealerEntity>
            <ns2:ReturnUpdateList>
                <ns2:ReturnUpdateProperties>
                    <ns2:DocumentNumber>0020014759</ns2:DocumentNumber>
                    <ns2:PurchaseOrderNumber>CHG1</ns2:PurchaseOrderNumber>
                    <ns2:Status>SAVED</ns2:Status>
                    <ns2:DateSubmitted>0000-00-00</ns2:DateSubmitted>
                    <ns2:RequestedPickupDate/>
                    <ns2:ReturnUpdateItemDetails>
                        <ns2:DocumentNumber></ns2:DocumentNumber>
                        <ns2:ItemNumber>000010</ns2:ItemNumber>
                        <ns2:ProductInformation>
                            <ns2:ProductIdentification>
                                <ns2:ProductIdentifier Type="SAP">CANOLA</ns2:ProductIdentifier>
                                <ns2:ProductName>DKL27-20 RR 50# GSSANG</ns2:ProductName>
                            </ns2:ProductIdentification>
                            <ns2:BatchNumber>4421-AAA1</ns2:BatchNumber>
                            <ns2:ItemAction>Update</ns2:ItemAction>
                            <ns2:ScheduledPickupDate>0000-00-00</ns2:ScheduledPickupDate>
                            <ns2:BaseQuantity>
                                <ns2:Measurement>
                                    <ns2:MeasurementValue>40</ns2:MeasurementValue>
                                </ns2:Measurement>
                            </ns2:BaseQuantity>
                        </ns2:ProductInformation>
                    </ns2:ReturnUpdateItemDetails>
                    <ns2:ReturnUpdateItemDetails>
                        <ns2:DocumentNumber></ns2:DocumentNumber>
                        <ns2:ItemNumber>000020</ns2:ItemNumber>
                        <ns2:ProductInformation>
                            <ns2:ProductIdentification>
                                <ns2:ProductIdentifier Type="SAP">CANOLA</ns2:ProductIdentifier>
                                <ns2:ProductName>DKL27-20 RR 50#</ns2:ProductName>
                            </ns2:ProductIdentification>
                            <ns2:BatchNumber>4421-AAA2</ns2:BatchNumber>
                            <ns2:ScheduledPickupDate>0000-00-00</ns2:ScheduledPickupDate>
                            <ns2:BaseQuantity>
                                <ns2:Measurement>
                                    <ns2:MeasurementValue>80</ns2:MeasurementValue>
                                </ns2:Measurement>
                            </ns2:BaseQuantity>
                        </ns2:ProductInformation>
                    </ns2:ReturnUpdateItemDetails>
                </ns2:ReturnUpdateProperties>
            </ns2:ReturnUpdateList>
        </ns2:ReturnUpdateRequestBody>
    </ns2:ReturnUpdateRequest>
</S:Body>
```

**Code**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" xmlns:dpconfig="http://www.datapower.com/param/config" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp dpconfig" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mon="Monsanto:ServiceReturnDetail" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <!--    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>-->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!--<dp:remove-http-request-header name="Accept"/>-->
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <urn:YSdsaUsseedRetUpdate>
                    <IIdent>
                        <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='Header']/*[local-name()='DocumentIdentifier']"/>
                    </IIdent>
                    <ISrc>
                        <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='DealerEntity']/*[local-name()='PartnerIdentifier']/@*[local-name()='Type']"/>
                    </ISrc>
                    <ItHdr>
                        <item>
                        <xsl:if test="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/mon:ReturnUpdateRequest/mon:ReturnUpdateRequestBody/mon:ReturnUpdateList/mon:ReturnUpdateProperties/mon:DocumentNumber != ' ' " >
                            <Yyvbeln>
                                <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/*[local-name()='DocumentNumber']"/>
                            </Yyvbeln>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <YyreqType>
                                <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/*[local-name()='DocumentNumber']"/>
                            </YyreqType>
                            <Yykunnr>
                                <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='DealerEntity']/*[local-name()='PartnerIdentifier']"/>
                            </Yykunnr>
                            <Yyzuonr>
                                <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/*[local-name()='PurchaseOrderNumber']"/>
                            </Yyzuonr>
                            <Yystatus>
                                <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/*[local-name()='Status']"/>
                            </Yystatus>
                            <Yybstdk>
                                <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/*[local-name()='RequestedPickupDate']"/>
                            </Yybstdk>
                            <Yymahdt>
                                <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/*[local-name()='DateSubmitted']"/>
                            </Yymahdt>
                            <Yyuser>
                                <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/*[local-name()='UserId']"/>
                            </Yyuser>
                        </item>
                    </ItHdr>
                    <ItItem>
                        <xsl:for-each select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateItemDetails']">
                            <item>
                                <xsl:if test="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateItemDetails']/*[local-name()='DocumentNumber'] != ' ' " >
                            <Yyvbeln>
                                <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/*[local-name()='DocumentNumber']"/>
                            </Yyvbeln>
                            </xsl:if>
                                <Yyitm>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateItemDetails']/*[local-name()='ItemNumber']"/>
                                </Yyitm>
                                <YymatEn>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateItemDetails']/*[local-name()='ProductInformation']/*[local-name()='ProductIdentification']/*[local-name()='ProductIdentifier']/@*[local-name()='Type']"/>
                                </YymatEn>
                                <Yymatnr>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateItemDetails']/*[local-name()='ProductInformation']/*[local-name()='ProductIdentification']/*[local-name()='ProductIdentifier']"/>
                                </Yymatnr>
                                <Yykdmat>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateItemDetails']/*[local-name()='ProductInformation']/*[local-name()='BatchNumber']"/>
                                </Yykdmat>
                                <Yyzmeng>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateItemDetails']/*[local-name()='ProductInformation']/*[local-name()='BaseQuantity']/*[local-name()='Measurement']/*[local-name()='MeasurementValue']"/>
                                </Yyzmeng>
                                <Yyzieme>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateItemDetails']/*[local-name()='ProductInformation']/*[local-name()='BaseQuantity']/*[local-name()='Measurement']/*[local-name()='UnitOfMeasureCode']"/>
                                </Yyzieme>
                                <Yyaction>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateItemDetails']/*[local-name()='ProductInformation']/*[local-name()='ItemAction']"/>
                                </Yyaction>
                            </item>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </ItItem>
                </urn:YSdsaUsseedRetUpdate>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I am getting from the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mon="Monsanto:ServiceReturnDetail" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:YSdsaUsseedRetUpdate>
            <IIdent>0001013083-1436198976111</IIdent>
            <ISrc>SAP_ID</ISrc>
            <ItHdr>
                <item>
                    <YyreqType>0020014759</YyreqType>
                    <Yykunnr>0001013083</Yykunnr>
                    <Yyzuonr>CHG1</Yyzuonr>
                    <Yystatus>SAVED</Yystatus>
                    <Yybstdk/>
                    <Yymahdt>0000-00-00</Yymahdt>
                    <Yyuser/>
                </item>
            </ItHdr>
            <ItItem>
                <item>
                    <Yyvbeln/>
                    <Yyitm>000010</Yyitm>
                    <YymatEn>SAP</YymatEn>
                    <Yymatnr>CANOLA</Yymatnr>
                    <Yykdmat>4421-AAA1</Yykdmat>
                    <Yyzmeng>40</Yyzmeng>
                    <Yyzieme/>
                    <Yyaction>Update</Yyaction>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <Yyvbeln/>
                    <Yyitm>000010</Yyitm>
                    <YymatEn>SAP</YymatEn>
                    <Yymatnr>CANOLA</Yymatnr>
                    <Yykdmat>4421-AAA1</Yykdmat>
                    <Yyzmeng>40</Yyzmeng>
                    <Yyzieme/>
                    <Yyaction>Update</Yyaction>
                </item>
            </ItItem>
        </urn:YSdsaUsseedRetUpdate>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The expected output should get the updated values `<ns2:ItemNumber>000010</ns2:ItemNumber>` for each I am doing it. For some reason I am getting the same value.

Expected output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mon="Monsanto:ServiceReturnDetail" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:YSdsaUsseedRetUpdate>
            <IIdent>0001013083-1436198976111</IIdent>
            <ISrc>SAP_ID</ISrc>
            <ItHdr>
                <item>
                    <YyreqType>0020014759</YyreqType>
                    <Yykunnr>0001013083</Yykunnr>
                    <Yyzuonr>CHG1</Yyzuonr>
                    <Yystatus>SAVED</Yystatus>
                    <Yybstdk/>
                    <Yymahdt>0000-00-00</Yymahdt>
                    <Yyuser/>
                </item>
            </ItHdr>
            <ItItem>
                <item>
                    <Yyvbeln/>
                    <Yyitm>000010</Yyitm>
                    <YymatEn>SAP</YymatEn>
                    <Yymatnr>CANOLA</Yymatnr>
                    <Yykdmat>4421-AAA1</Yykdmat>
                    <Yyzmeng>40</Yyzmeng>
                    <Yyzieme/>
                    <Yyaction>Update</Yyaction>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <Yyvbeln/>
                    <Yyitm>000020</Yyitm>
                    <YymatEn>SAP</YymatEn>
                    <Yymatnr>CANOLA</Yymatnr>
                    <Yykdmat>4421-AAA1</Yykdmat>
                    <Yyzmeng>80</Yyzmeng>
                    <Yyzieme/>
                    <Yyaction>Update</Yyaction>
                </item>
            </ItItem>
        </urn:YSdsaUsseedRetUpdate>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Update**. Thanks LarsH for the suggestion.

```
YymatEn>
            <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='ProductIdentifier']/@*[local-name()='Type']"/>
        </YymatEn>
        <Yymatnr>
            <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='ProductIdentifier']"/>
        </Yymatnr>
        <Yykdmat>
            <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='BatchNumber']"/>
        </Yykdmat>
        <Yyzmeng>
            <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='MeasurementValue']"/>
        </Yyzmeng>
        <Yyzieme>
            <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='UnitOfMeasureCode']"/>
        </Yyzieme>
        <Yyaction>
            <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='ItemAction']"/>
        </Yyaction>
```

I have tried all above statement, but for some reason I didn't got the values.

Comment: If only every question-asker would include actual output and expected output, as you have done. +1. On the other hand, there's so much of the expected/actual output, the code is so wide (side-scrolling), and sometimes improperly indented, that it's hard to see the difference between what you expected and what you got and trace it to the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the problem you're seeing is that your code isn't using the context selected by the for-each on each iteration.

For example, when you do

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/
  *[local-name()='Body']/
  *[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/
  *[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequestBody']/
  *[local-name()='ReturnUpdateList']/
  *[local-name()='ReturnUpdateProperties']/
  *[local-name()='ReturnUpdateItemDetails']">
```

The code inside the for-each operates in the context of a `ReturnUpdateItemDetails` element... once for each selected `ReturnUpdateItemDetails` element. So that code should use the context element to proceed:

```
<item>
  <xsl:if test="*[local-name()='DocumentNumber'] != ' ' " >
```

Notice that I chopped off all the initial part of the XPath expression that navigated from the root, and used the context node. If you start from the root each time, you will be selecting *all* the `DocumentNumber` elements that match that XPath expression, instead of iterating over them one at a time. In some usages, that means you end up just getting the value of the first one, every time.

So you'll want to do the same for every XPath expression inside the for-each: get rid of the part already selected by the for-each, and use the context node. E.g.

```
<Yyitm>
  <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='ItemNumber']"/>
</Yyitm>
```

There's much more to say about using XSLT as it's meant to be used, e.g. using namespaces instead of avoiding them, and using templates. But that's better approached by reading an XSLT tutorial or book than by a Q&A. (Check the resources on the [xslt](/questions/tagged/xslt) tag's info page.)

## Update in response to comment

Again, if your for-each XPath ends with `*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateItemDetails']`, you are selecting a `ReturnUpdateItemDetails` element each time as the context node. So for example, instead of

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='ProductIdentifier']/@*[local-name()='Type']"/>
```

you need to start from `ReturnUpdateItemDetails`, e.g. by selecting one of its children, `ProductInformation` followed by `ProductIdentification` before you can get to `ProductIdentifier`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ns2:ProductInformation/ns2:ProductIdentification/
  ns2:ProductIdentifier/@Type" />
```

where the `ns2` namespace prefix is declared up on an ancestor element of your code (e.g. on `<soapenv:Envelope>`):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ns2="ibm:ServiceReturnUpdate"
   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ...
```

I would highly recommend getting a better grounding in the basics of XPath and XSLT before trying to push further by trial and error.

Comment: Thank LarsH. Can you please suggest me what I am doing wrong in Update section of the post?

Comment: P.S. You don't need any namespace shenanigans (`local-name() = ...`) for the `Type` attribute, because it's not in a namespace.

Comment: Thank you I just figured it out where I was doing it wrong.